# How to Pass Query String to local html file from xcode ios app

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I have follwing code that load html file in to webview

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"htm"];
NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
if (htmlData) {
[webView loadData:htmlData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"localhost/..."]];
}
```

but I want to pass data or value as query string to the calling html file so that I could receive them at html side using java script.